# What version of Space Invaders is this?

Tags: arcade

I would like to know which manufacturer/version is the Space Invaders game that I show playing in the video linked below. The game setup is similar to Galaxian/Galaga but it is not. It also feels faster/ more dynamic (or maybe it's just me)
https://youtu.be/eng16esbe7Y

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the video title and the arcade art, that's Namco's [Gaplus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaplus), which is Galaga 3 outside of the USA. See also its [Arcade Museum entry](https://www.arcade-museum.com/game_detail.php?game_id=7911).

Here's a [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/2SWqdUfv7J4?t=135) starting at the same place in the game as the video you've provided; if the time offset doesn't work then skip to 2:15.

Comment: Hi Tomy, thanks for your answer. However I am confused because the enemies are not bees or insect like creatures like in the Galaga game. They are actual “aliens” similar to the ones that showed in the original Space Invaders game. I am the player that shows in the video I posted, and I’m sure of that. To me it didn’t look at all like Galaga, although the behaviour was very similar or maybe identical. Any ideas?

Comment: They look the same to me. Look at the bottom of the top row of enemies from the first set that appears. Look *carefully* and you'll see the flapping wings. It's just that the color and contrast are muted so its hard to see.

Comment: Hi Maury. I appreciate that the video I recorded is not clear enough, but I can tell with absolute certainty that the “enemies” in that game are not at all like the fat bees that appear on the galaga/gaplus game as shown by Tommy. So it’s definitely another version or maybe a tweak of the original with different enemy art. I also recall this game from the early 80’s or so, (only in Europe) and the enemies were not ‘insects’ but alien like figures.

Comment: On a second thought, maybe I have always seen the game being run on old worn out crc screens (also in the 80s) and thus the enemies never appeared to me as such colourful ‘insects’ that modern displays show. It may be right after all that this was just the normal gaplus game.

Comment: A hack is definitely another option — they weren't exactly uncommon in those days. From the video, clearly the enemy patterns are the same, so someone creating an unlicensed Space Invaders sequel is certainly possible.